# Writing HTML code with Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping

```
<% @ticket.conversations.each do |c| %>

<section class="messages">

<%="<li> #{c.the_message} </li>" %>

</section>

<%end%>
```

I am trying to have rails write the HTML code for me so the output would look something like this:

```
<li>MESSAGE1</li>
<li>MESSAGE2</li>
<li>Next message here...</li>
```

I am going to style every nth element to have a different style to show what speaker it belongs to. But currently is just outputs straight text and escapes the HTML. How do I stop this escape?

Comment: You'll still get unpredictable results after you fix the HTML encoding problem, [`<section>` is not a valid parent for `<li>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html). The browser is free to rewrite invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

To output you need to use `<%=` as follows within your `<section>` block:

```
<%= "<li> #{c.the_message} </li>".html_safe %>
```

> But currently is just outputs straight text and escapes the HTML

You can use the `html_safe` method.  Please refer to the "Extensions to String" topic in this document: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html

Another option you can use is the `raw` helper(as pointed out by Stefan) which calls the `html_safe` for you. e.g.

```
<%= raw "<li> #{c.the_message} </li>" %>
```

Comment: That still gives me the same issue. It shows the entire statement with the html tags included. It escapes the HTML.

Comment: @DaveyGravy, Please try the updated answer.  I think you want to use the `html_safe` method which should give you your desired output.

Comment: `html_safe` should not be used in ordinary views, use `<%= raw "..." %>` or `<%== "..." %>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also style your list items this way:

```
<li><%= c.the_message %></li>
```

Just based upon preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
<% @ticket.conversations.each do |c| %>
  <section class="messages">
    <li><%= c.the_message %></li>
  </section>
<% end %>
```

Or if you don't want to repeat `<section>` every time:

```
<section class="messages">
  <% @ticket.conversations.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= c.the_message %></li>
  <% end %>
</section>
```